# Java Poi How to dynamically build cell height?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Okay I have

```
 float someVar; // ?
//mySheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints() = 15
someRow.setHeightInPoints(mySheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints() * someVar)
```

I have the length of the the data that would go in the cell and I also do an newline ever 47th character.

Can anyone think of a formula that would work with this?..

When I have a length of 389-588..`temp = 19` seems to give me enough room, but thats a broad span

any suggestions would be heplful

Comment: Divide the length by 47 and add 1.  Multiply the result by the default row height.

Comment: trying this right now...

Comment: Why you want to change the height? I mean you can wrap the texts as well, which will automatically fit to the required height.

Comment: If I have a default height with a cell that has data with a length past the default, then the data wont show...poi does not have height resizing...they only have width auto-resizing